# Accounts with expiry date and manager's name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get a list of users whose password will expire in 7 days, together with their manager's name.

This is my best guess:

```
Search-ADAccount -SearchBase "O..." -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 07.00:00:00 | ` 
where {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'user'} | `
Get-ADUser -Properties Name, Manager, AccountExpirationDate | `
Select Name, Manager, AccountExpirationDate | Out-GridView -notype
```

The problem is that I get the full object of the Manager and I only want his Display Name.

I read that I could use:

```
Select-Object Name, @{n="ManagerName";e={(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Manager -Properties displayName).DisplayName}}
```

to get it, but I can't get it to fit into my script.

Comment: What do you mean by "my best guess"? Did you try running it? Do you get an error?

Comment: I meant, I ran the first part and that works, but I can't integrate the 2nd one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the property `Manager` in this part of your code:

```
... | Select Name, Manager, AccountExpirationDate | ...
```

with the calculated property:

```
... | Select Name, @{n="ManagerName";e={(Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Manager -Properties displayName).DisplayName}}, AccountExpirationDate | ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be pretty slow if you're running this in a large domain.  Calculated properties are extremely slow.  I wrote about [this on my blog](http://www.adamtheautomator.com/little-code-change-makes-huge-difference/).  To get what you're looking for I'd use a single Get-AdUser cmdlet by doing something like this:

```
$7DaysAgo = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)
$Today = Get-Date

Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $true } -Properties AccountExpirationDate,Manager | Where-Object { ($AccountExpirationDate -ge $7DaysAgo) -and ($AccountExpirationDate -lt $Today)} | Select-Object Name,Manager,AccountExpirationDate | Out-GridView
```

Comment: I've edited my answer.  That makes it a lot easier because AccountExpirationDate is a default property with Get-AdUser.